# Character inventory in C#

Tags: c#, adventure-game

Here are the relevant parts of a project I'm working on that's working perfectly. I was wondering what I should change to improve it (to respect SOLID principle for example), especially regarding my add/remove loot functions which, even though they work, don't really feel right.

```
public class Hero
{

    private int gold { get; set; }
    public event GoldHandler GoldChanged;
    public delegate void GoldHandler(Hero m, int goldChange);

    public BackPack backPack { get; set; }
    public event backPackHandler backPackChanged;
    public delegate void backPackHandler(Hero m, Item item, bool add);

    public WeaponHolder weaponHolder { get; set; }
    public event weaponHolderHandler weaponHolderChanged;
    public delegate void weaponHolderHandler(Hero m, Weapon weapon, bool add);

    private Hero()
    {

    }

    public Hero(string name)
    {
        this.gold = 0;
        backPack = new BackPack();
        weaponHolder = new WeaponHolder();
    }
    public void addLoot(Loot loot)
    {
        if (loot is Weapon)
        {
            this.addWeapon((Weapon)loot);
            return;
        }
        if (loot is Item)
        {
            this.addBackPackItem((Item)loot);
            return;
        }
        if (loot is Gold)
        {
            this.addGold(((Gold)loot).getGoldAmount);
        }
    }

    public void removeLoot(Loot loot)
    {
        if (loot is Weapon)
        {
            this.removeWeapon((Weapon)loot);
            return;
        }
        if (loot is Item)
        {
            this.removeBackPackItem((Item)loot);
            return;
        }
        if (loot is Gold)
        {
            this.removeGold(((Gold)loot).getGoldAmount);
        }
    }
    public int getGold()
    {
        return this.gold;
    }

    public void addGold(int gold)
    {
        this.gold += gold;
        GoldHasChanged(gold);
    }
    public void removeGold(int gold)
    {
        if ((this.gold - gold) >= 0)
        {

            this.gold -= gold;
            GoldHasChanged(-gold);
        }

    }
    public void emptyGold()
    {
        int tempoGold = this.gold;
        this.gold = 0;
        GoldHasChanged(-tempoGold);
    }
    public void GoldHasChanged(int gold)
    {
        GoldHandler handler = GoldChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler((Hero)this, gold);
        }
    }
    private void addWeapon(Weapon weapon)
    {
        this.weaponHolder.Add(weapon);
        weaponHolderHasChanged(weapon, true);
    }
    private void removeWeapon(Weapon weapon)
    {
        this.weaponHolder.Remove(weapon);
        weaponHolderHasChanged(weapon, false);
    }
    public void weaponHolderHasChanged(Weapon weapon, bool add)
    {
        weaponHolderHandler handler = weaponHolderChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler((Hero)this, weapon, add);
        }
    }

    private void addBackPackItem(Item item)
    {
        this.backPack.Add(item);
        backPackItemHasChanged(item, true);
    }
    private bool removeBackPackItem(Item item)
    {
        if (this.backPack.Remove(item))
        {
            backPackItemHasChanged(item, false);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    public void backPackItemHasChanged(Item item, bool add)
    {
        backPackHandler handler = backPackChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler((Hero)this, item, add);
        }
    }

    public void useItem(Item item)
    {
            item.use(this);
            backPackItemHasChanged(item, false);
    }

}

public abstract class Loot
{

}
public class Gold : Loot
{
    int goldAmount;
    private Gold()
    {

    }
    public Gold(int amount)
    {
        this.goldAmount = amount;
    }
    public int getGoldAmount
    {
        get { return this.goldAmount; }
    }
}
public abstract class Item : Loot
{
    protected string name{get;set;}

    public string getName
    {
        get { return name; }
    }
    public abstract void use(Hero hero);
}

public class Consummable : Item
{

    int healingPower{get;set;}
    int chargesLeft { get; set; }

    private Consummable()
    {

    }
    public Consummable(string name, int healingPower, int charges)
    {
        this.healingPower = healingPower;
        this.name = name;
        this.chargesLeft = charges;
    }
    public override void use(Hero hero)
    {
        if (chargesLeft >= 1)
        {
            this.chargesLeft--;
        }
    }

}

public class Food : Item
{
    int chargesLeft { get; set; }
    private Food()
    {

    }
    public Food(string name, int charges)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.chargesLeft = charges;
    }

    public override void use(Hero hero)
    {
        if (chargesLeft >= 1)
        { 
            this.chargesLeft--;
        }
    }

}



public class Weapon : Loot
{
    private string name{get;set;}
    private WeaponTypes weaponType { get; set; }

    private Weapon()
    {

    }
    public Weapon(string name, WeaponTypes weaponType){
        this.name = name;
        this.weaponType = weaponType;
    }

    public WeaponTypes getWeaponType
    {
        get { return weaponType; }
    }
}
public enum WeaponTypes
{
    Sword,
    Spear,
    Mace,
    Dagger,
    Sabre,
    WarHammer,
    Axe,
    Baton,
    TwoEdgedSword,
    None
}


public class WeaponHolder
{
    List<Weapon> weapons;

    public WeaponHolder()
    {
        weapons = new List<Weapon>();
    }

    public void Add(Weapon weapon)
    {
            this.weapons.Add(weapon);
    }
    public void Remove(Weapon weapon)
    {
        this.weapons.Remove(weapon);
    }

    public bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (this.weapons.Count == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public List<Weapon> getWeapons
    {
        get { return weapons;}
    }

}


 public class BackPack
{
    public List<Item> items;

    public BackPack()
    {
        this.items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public void Add(Item backPackItem)
    {
            this.items.Add(backPackItem);
    }

    public bool Remove(Item backPackItem)
    {
        return this.items.Remove(backPackItem);
    }

    public List<Item> getItems
    {
        get { return items; }
    }

}
```

Comment: From what it looks like, you have 3 model objects (model as in **M**VC), that is: an observable object that informs observers about a change in its value. The difference between the 3 is just the type of the value (`Weapon`, `Item` or `Gold`). I suspect that you could write a generic `Model<T>` class (possibly used as base class) and save a lot of duplicated code that you have right now.

Answer (score 3):

**WeaponTypes**

> ```
> public enum WeaponTypes
> {
>   Sword,
>   Spear,
>   Mace,
>   Dagger,
>   Sabre,
>   WarHammer,
>   Axe,
>   Baton,
>   TwoEdgedSword,
>   None
> }
> ```

The `None` value should be first as the first value is always the default value if don't set any other. You could provide another field that you call `Default` and set it to any other field but `Sword` by default is counter intuitive to me.

**Hero**

Your hero uses a backpack and a weapon-holder classes but instead using them and adding items there you perform the actions on the hero where you implement add-weapon or add-loot.

**Loot**

This base class should provide a protected constructor that requries you to specify a name. This way you won't forget it. The `Name` setter should be in this case private.

If you make the `Name` property public you don't need the `getName` method which is redundant anyway. We have access modifiers so that we don't have to write such methods. (the same situation with weapon).

**Weapon**

You don't need a private default constructor that you don't use anyway. As soon as you define a custom one the default one is no longer automaitcally created.

**WeaponHolder/BackPack**

Instead of having a `getWeapons` method there, your `WeaponHolder` could implement the `IEnumerable<Weapon>` interface and return the values instead of revealing the internal list.

In fact you actually need one of them and rename it to something like `ItemHolder<TItem>` and make it generic. This could then hold either weapons or loot as they are nearly identical. You just create two different instances of it `new ItemHolder<Weapon>()` and `new ItemHolder<Loot>()`

**Consummable/Item/Food**

Food is consumable so food should have the members that the consummable currently has. This class is redundant... but you don't use it anywhere :-|

**Names**

In C# we use PascalCase for all public members.

Comment: Thanks for your advices, I'll look into that.
Just regarding my " private default constructor that I don't use anyway", in fact it's a "trick" required to make my class works with EntityFrameWork, it requires an empty constructor in order to work

Comment: @Belterius oh, I couldn't have known that, then it's ok ;-)

Comment: Well, the project is way bigger than what I've posted, but I don't think I would have gotten much help if I tried to post the entire thing, I don't know what's the etiquette regarding "big" project, same for my consumable class, I use it, but the part where I do didn't seem relevant. (the entire project is available here https://github.com/Belterius/LDVELH/tree/WPFBranch/LDVELH_WPF but I'm not sure if I should add the link in my main post)

Comment: @Belterius less code it usually better but sometimes it's inevitable if it's something like a framework... in your case I find it's perfect.

Comment: @t3chb0t Regarding enum defaults, it would be more precise to say that the enum corresponding to zero is set as default (even if you have none!)

Comment: @eurotrash I didn't know that :-o